# Reusing ImageView Crashes the application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitextfield

I have initialized an image view with a image:

```
validRightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"validationTick.png"]];
```

Wanted to reuse this same image view in multiple textFields as it's right view.

```
self.txtName.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.txtCountry.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
self.txtName.rightView = validRightImageView;
self.txtCountry.rightView = validRightImageView ;
```

This crashes the app and shows this error after one minute in a log:

> *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
>
> *** error: can't allocate region securely
>
> *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

What's the reason behind it and how to solve the problem. I want to reuse the same image in multiple textFields.

Answer (score 1):

You have one image object but set it to display in two places at the same time. If you want to displays same image in text fields you should create image object for each text field.